# OpenCart loading project goes to install/index.php which is NOT FOUND

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart2.3

I have cloned an Open Cart project into `htdocs` directory of XAMPP and in this cloned project there is a file named `config-dist.php` and I have changed that to `config.php` with these credentials:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');    
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');         
define('DB_DATABASE', 'shop'); 
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
```

Now when I want to load the project from this url: `http://localhost/shop` it suddenly goes to `http://localhost/shop/install/index.php` and prints this:

**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.**

I don't know why it redirects to this url while there is no `install` directory in the project at all!

So how to solve this issue and load this opencart project via Xampp?

Also mention that there is no `.htaccess` in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add this difination to your config file

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'Your directory to catalog folder');
```

then your application will started normally.